# franchise/branch relations with user laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am unable to find best suited relations for creating a courier website.
my requirements are

1. a branch can have many users
2. a franchise can be associated with only one user
3. a branch can have many franchise
4. branch user can access through franchise models

Note:- branch and franchise have different profiles

Answer (score 1):

I want to avoid directly jumping to the answer and convert the statements you have given into more easier relationship descriptions :

```
- 1 branch has many franchises
- 1 user has 1 franchise
```

This will then help you to understand :

```
- branch <> franchises is one to many relationship
- franchise <> user is one to one relationship
```

Models :

`Branch` Model :

```
public function franchises()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Franchise::class);
}
```

`Franchise` Model :

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`User` Model :

```
public function franchise()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

To make  these relationships work, you need to have proper foreign keys in your database schema. To know more please check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)